# インスタンス作成時にコンストラクタ実行が必要な理由は？

Tags: java

以下のプログラムで、Circleクラスを自作で作りました（オブジェクト指向）
最初にCircleクラスの配列circlesを用意して（数は20）、その下のfor文でCircleクラスのインスタンスをn回生成しているのですが、ここでなぜ `public Sample83(){}` と、わざわざSample83のコンストラクタをする必要があるのでしょうか？

```
int n = 20;
   Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];

   for (int i = 0; i<n;++i)
      {circles[i]  = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30+40*i, 100, 15);
      }
```

配列circlesを作ったら、そのまま続けてfor文を書けばいいと思うのですが、この様にするとエラーが出てしまいます。

元のコードは以下の通りです。

```
import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

  public class Sample83 extends JPanel {
   int n = 20;
   Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];

   public Sample83() {
      for (int i = 0; i<n;++i)
      {circles[i]  = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30+40*i, 100, 15);
      }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {circles[i].draw(g); }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame app = new JFrame();
      app.add(new Sample83());
      app.setSize(880, 300);
      app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      app.setVisible(true);
    }
    static class Circle {
      Color col;
      int xpos, ypos, rad;
      public Circle(Color c, int x, int y, int r) {
        col = c; xpos = x; ypos = y; rad = r;
      }
      public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillOval(xpos-rad, ypos-rad, rad*2, rad*2);
      }
    }
  }
```

2つ目のプログラムを追記します。このプログラムでは「文」である
”Circle c1 = new Circle(new Color(200,200,0), 150, 90, 50);”
などが、クラスSample82直下に記入できています。1つ目のプログラムでは、直下ではなく、Sample83のコンストラクタを実行する必要がありますが（「文」なのでブロック{}の中に書く必要があると聞きました)が、なぜ2つ目のプログラムはクラスの定義に直接かけるのでしょうか？

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sample82 extends JPanel {
  Circle c1 = new Circle(new Color(200,200,0), 150, 90, 50);
  Circle c2 = new Circle(new Color(0,200,200), 150, 90, 40);
  Circle c3 = new Circle(new Color(200,0,200), 150, 90, 30);
  Rect r1 = new Rect(Color.GREEN, 270, 180, 80, 50);
  Triangle t1 = new Triangle(Color.YELLOW, 50, 220, 250, 180, 150, 150);

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    c1.draw(g); c2.draw(g);c3.draw(g); r1.draw(g); t1.draw(g);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame app = new JFrame();
    app.add(new Sample82());
    app.setSize(400, 300);
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setVisible(true);
  }
  static class Circle {
    Color col;
    int xpos, ypos, rad;
    public Circle(Color c, int x, int y, int r) {
      col = c; xpos = x; ypos = y; rad = r;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(col);
      g.fillOval(xpos-rad, ypos-rad, rad*2, rad*2);
    }
  }
  static class Rect {
    Color col;
    int xpos, ypos, width, height;
    public Rect(Color c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      col = c; xpos = x; ypos = y; width = w; height = h;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(col);
      g.fillRect(xpos-width/2, ypos-height/2, width, height);
    }
  }
  static class Triangle {
    Color col;
    int[] xa, ya;
    public Triangle(Color c, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1,
                    int x2, int y2) {
      col = c; xa = new int[]{x0,x1,x2}; ya = new int[]{y0,y1,y2};
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(col); g.fillPolygon(xa, ya, 3);
    }
  }
}
```

・追加で質問です。
下の様に変数宣言の2行を、Sample83のコンストラクタ{}の中に書いて実行したところエラーが出ました。どうやらこの2行は外に書く必要があるみたいですが、なぜでしょうか？

エラー内容：
シンボルを見つけられません（シンボル：n,circles）

```
public Sample83() {
    int n = 20;
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];
      for (int i = 0; i<n;++i)
      {circles[i]  = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30+40*i, 100, 15);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *なぜ public Sample83(){} と、わざわざSample83のコンストラクタをする必要がある*

Javaにおいては、クラスの直下には「文」を書くことができないためです。

Javaにおいて、

- `int n = 20;`
- `Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];`

などは、変数宣言(もう少し正確に言うと、今回の場合「インスタンスフィールドの宣言」)であり、このような「宣言」は`class`の直下に書けます。(これらは「代入文」ではありません。)

それに対して、

- `for (int i = 0; i<n;++i) {...}`
- `circles[i]  = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30+40*i, 100, 15);`

等々は、「文」(2つ目はいわゆる「代入文」、正確に言うと『代入演算子のある「式文」』)であり、Javaの場合、「文」を置くことができるのは、メソッド本体などの`{`と`}`で囲まれた「ブロック」の中だけで、クラス定義の本体部分に直接記載することは出来ません。

[8.1. Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)

[14.5. Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)

上記の公式ドキュメントの記載はとても見やすいとは言えないですし、内容や公式の用語を丸暗記しなければJavaのプログラミングができないと言うものでもないですが、

**「文」と「宣言」の違いが把握できていないと、今後確実に苦労する**

ことになるため、その辺りの違い(特に「代入文」と「初期値を指定した変数宣言」の違い、同じ変数宣言でもフィールドの宣言とローカル変数の宣言の違い)は、強く意識されていった方が良いでしょう。

---

#### 2つ目のプログラムについて

この回答の中身をまだ十分ご理解いただいていないように思います。

繰り返しになりますが、

- `Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];`は変数宣言
- `circles[i]  = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30+40*i, 100, 15);`は代入文

です。

あなたの引用された、

`Circle c1 = new Circle(new Color(200,200,0), 150, 90, 50);`

は、変数宣言ですので、『「文」である』と言う判断が誤っています。

2つ目のプログラムで、以下は全て「文」ではなく、変数宣言です。

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(new Color(200,200,0), 150, 90, 50);
Circle c2 = new Circle(new Color(0,200,200), 150, 90, 40);
Circle c3 = new Circle(new Color(200,0,200), 150, 90, 30);
Rect r1 = new Rect(Color.GREEN, 270, 180, 80, 50);
Triangle t1 = new Triangle(Color.YELLOW, 50, 220, 250, 180, 150, 150);
```

---

#### 変数宣言と文

あまり厳密に公式ドキュメントの構文規則を引用してもわかりにくいだけなので、ざっくりまとめると、先頭(`public`だの`private`だのがあればその後)に「型」が記載されていれば、それは「宣言」になります。

```
Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];
--------
↑型
```

ちょっとだけ一般化すると、

```
型 変数名;
```

または、

```
型 変数名 = 初期化式;
```

と言う構文になっているのが変数宣言です。

それに対して、先頭に「型」が記載されておらず、

```
変数名 = 式;
```

と言う構文になっているものは、「文」になります。
(Javaでは、`変数名 = 式`全体も有効な「式」なので、後ろに`;`をつけて「文」として扱ったものを「式文」と言ったりします。)

初期化式を伴う変数宣言では、「代入」に相当する処理が行われると言うのは間違いありませんが、そのことと「宣言」であるか「文」であるかとは関係ありません。

---

#### *追加で質問* について

ここまでのこの回答では、「宣言」と「文」の区別に焦点を当てたかったので、細かい違いは無視して「変数宣言」として扱ってきたのですが、省略しすぎてわかりにくいものになってしまったようです。

「変数宣言」は、どこに書かれるかにより、大きく2つに分けられます。

- クラス本体の直下に記載した場合、「フィールド宣言」になります

  `static`のつかない「インスタンスフィールド」の宣言の場合、インスタンスが作られると同時にフィールド用の領域が確保され、インスタンスがガーベッジコレクションで回収されてなくなってしまうまで、存在し続けます。また、インスタンスフィールドはそのクラス内の全てのコンストラクタ、インスタンスメソッドで参照できます。
- ブロック内に記載した場合、「ローカル変数の宣言」になります

  ローカル変数として宣言された変数は、そのブロックの実行開始時に領域が確保され、ブロック自体の実行が終わると、その領域は開放されてしまいます。また、そのブロックの外から参照することは出来ません。

したがって、

```
    public Sample83() {
        //↓↓↓「このブロック」開始
        int n = 20;
        Circle[] circles = new Circle[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            circles[i] = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30 + 40 * i, 100, 15);
        }
        //↑↑↑「このブロック」終了
    }
```

のように、`n`と`circles`をコンストラクタのブロック内でを「宣言」してしまうと、そのブロックの外では、そんな変数は無かったことにされてしまうわけです。

`paintComponent()`メソッドの中では`n`や`circles`を参照しようとしていますが、「そんな変数は無かったことにされて」いますから、そこでエラーになります。

このような場合、「宣言」は、必ずクラス直下に記載しないといけない、と言うことになります。ただし、初期化(初期値の代入)は必ずしも宣言と一緒に行う必要はありません。

```
    //初期化無しのフィールド宣言
    int n;
    Circle[] circles;

    public Sample83() {
        //宣言無しの代入だけ
        n = 20;
        circles = new Circle[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            circles[i] = new Circle(Color.BLUE, 30 + 40 * i, 100, 15);
        }
    }
```

(ただし、初期化し忘れによるバグを防ぐために、宣言と同時に初期化してしまう方が良い習慣とされています。)

と言うわけで、さっきまでより覚えないといけない項目が増えてしまいましたが、

- フィールド宣言
- ローカル変数の宣言
- 代入文

は、区別できるようにして下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「Javaの場合、『文』を置くことができるのは、メソッド本体などの{}で囲まれた『ブロック』の中だけ」とのことですが、以下のプログラムはメソッド{}で囲まれていませんが、コンストラクタを実行しなくても問題ありません。どうしてでしょうか？

Comment: package max_min;
import java.util.*;

public class Max_Min{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      
      Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
      double max=0;
      double min=0;
      int i;
      double a;

      System.out.println("5個の数字の中から最大値と最小値を求めます。");

      for(i=1;i<6;i++){
         System.out.print(i+"つ目の数字:");
         a=scanner.nextDouble();

         if(a<=min){
             min=a;
         }else if(a>=max){
             max=a;
         }
      }

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa さん、コメント中に長いコードを書くのは、見にくくなるので、質問に追記してもらった方が良かったかもしれません。(元質問に強く関連しているので、「別質問にすべき」と言われるような内容ではないと思います。)で、お示しいただいたコードには「インスタンスフィールド」の宣言はありませんし、インスタンスメソッドもありませんので、インスタンスは作成する必要がありませんから、コンストラクタを呼ぶ必要もありません。ちなみに「文」が書かれているのは、`main(String[])`メソッドの本体を表す「`{`と`}`で囲まれた「ブロック」の中」ですので、何を持って「{}で囲まれていません」と言うのかよく理解できていません。もう少しご説明いただければ、回答を改善したいと思いますので、お知らせください。

Comment: 質問を追記しました。2つめのプログラムを追記しました。２つ目は配列がありません。この場合は、クラス定義の本体部分に書いても問題ないです。両者の違いはなんでしょうか？よろしくお願いします

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa さん、『「宣言」はクラス直下に記載できる』『「文」はブロック内に記載する必要がある』と言う点で全く違いはありません。何を持って「文」と言うかがまだ理解できていないように思われます。

Comment: 仰る通りです。何を持って「文」というかがまだ理解できていません。何を持って文というのでしょうか？

Comment: 私の理解ですと、この場合は、2つめは、newでコンストラクタを実行し、Circleクラスのインスタンスオブジェクトを生成し、それを変数c1,c2などにそれぞれ代入しているので、2つ目はc1,c2などの変数宣言であると理解しています。一方、1つ目は代入文と仰いましたが、これはfor「文」を使って指定した回数分代入しているから、「文」と言えるのでしょうか？1つ目も2つ目も「代入」という意味では同じだと思いますが、for「文」を使っているので、「文」であると認識しています。

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa さん、「変数宣言と文」については、本文中に追記しました。for文で繰り返しているかどうかも、「代入」に相当するかどうかも関係ありません。「変数宣言」の構文になっていれば、それは「変数宣言」ですし、「文」の構文になっていれば、それは「文」です。また『「代入」という意味では同じ』とありますが、変数宣言の目的はJavaのコンパイラに「この型の変数を格納するための領域の確保が必要であること」を伝える、と言う大きな意味があります。コンパイラ的には大きな違いのあることなので、構文的にも分けているのです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。では今回、Sample83のコンストラクタとして記述する必要がある理由は、「文」であるため、ブロックの中に書く必要があるから、ということでしょうか？（余談ですが、Sample83のコンストラクタではなく、例えばvoid mainなどのメソッドの中に書くことも出来ると思いますが、今回の場合は既に下にvoid mainのブロックがあるため使えないと思います）

Comment: 質問を追加させて頂きました。お時間ありましたら、ご確認頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: @DaisukeOgawa さん、『「文」であるため』についてはその通りです。宣言そのものは、「フィールド宣言」になるようにクラス直下から移動させるわけにはいきませんが、初期値を代入する部分だけ`main`メソッド内に移すと言うのは出来ないわけではありません。ただ、初期化が済んでないインスタンスフィールドに直接アクセスすると言うのは、作法的によろしくないとされているので、コードまで示すのはやめておきます。回答もコメントもかなり長く伸びてしまったのと、内容的にもだいぶ細かい話になってきたので、これ以上突っ込んだお話をされたい場合、新規のご質問としていただいたほうがいいだろうと思います。